# Animation not working properly in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a Veiw, that i am shifiting upwards, it consists of RelativeLayout and ListView.
When the view is move upwards, previous frame remains there, this is seen when scrolling the listview. What i am doing wrong please guide.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXBR72-ivm0&feature=youtu.be

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: - for ScrollView  - android:fillViewport="true"
- for the child of ScrollView (android:height="wrap_content")